# Create disk image of system with data on Dropboxsync

Tags: dropbox, disk-image

Every month I create a clone of my system disk (containing Ubuntu 20.04.6) using Clonezilla. Recently I started to save my work to Dropbox. For this I use the Ubuntu Dropbox app. The actual Dropbox directory is on another drive, but is simlinked to the home directory (required for Dropbox to work).
I wondered what would happen if I restored an older image: the simlink in the home directory points to the Dropbox directory on the other drive, so this should not reverse my files somehow right?